# how to check and make sure my host is have enough power for being CDN

Tags: cloud, cdn

Hi guys i have a question.

I have a host with some power for example with 8 core CPU and 16GB ram alowed and blob blob blob

And its on German vps so my question is how to make sure if i try to being CDN for my own websites in another hosts like 10 more website or 20 more website is it gonna work well?

I talking about power of this host and also the ping or i don't know what i can call for it but i want to make sure its gonna work well and its not gonna make my website slow.(my host is work very fast and strong its just a more information).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not a question that you can answer without testing.
You have to follow your experience on that one. For example:

if your websites don't get any traffic you may as well host 500 websites on a single VPS.
if you only have one website that is getting millions of hits daily then you probably need a larger web-server.

Required computation power is always a KPI that requires lots of research and has to do a lot with the application layer.

So other factors that needs to be taken into account is what do those 20 websites run?

Are they plain html/css ?
do they run php/mysql? 
are they built on wordpress?

etc.
hope it helps.